# Find the maximum value of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ in the region bounded by $y=\frac x2,y=-\frac x2$ and $x=y^2+1$,including the boundary lines

Tags: functions, area, curves

The figure of the problem  where $y=\frac x2,y=-\frac x2$ and $x=y^2+1$ enclose the region is this:

[image]

The shaded region is the enclosed area. Now the max of $x^2+y^2$ in this area is exactly what in this region?Is it the point where $y=\frac{x}{2}$ intersects $x^2+y^2$?

Comment: You must compute all intersection Points of the given curves.

Comment: You have shaded the wrong area

Comment: That little triangle touching origin with curved bases is to be shaded

Comment: Yes thats right @AFalseName that is right. i have forgotten. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the feasible region is the light blue region then the maximum for $x^2+y^2$ is $\infty$ otherwise if the feasible region is the white one the the maximum is attained at $(x_0,y_0)=(0,1)$ with value $x_0^2+y_0^2 = 1$

[image]

Comment: Why haven't you included point (2,1) and (2,-1) in feasable region. And where did you get the circle from? the question nowhere mention the circle. Except the firgure which is wrong in itself

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2$ is is square of distance from origin thus the point furtherest from the origin i.e $(2,1)$ and $(2,-1)$ lying on intersection of the parabola and the line are the optimal points with $f_{max}=5$

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The feasible region is the shaded region. The optimal point is at $(1,0)$.

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Hence:
$$f(1,0)=1 \ (max).$$

Comment: That's wrong, $f_{max}$ would occur at $(2,1)$ and $(2,-1)$

Comment: $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is the square of distance function thus the point most far away from Origin would be the answer